# Firebase Query unable to fech data in Xiaomi Redmi Y1 (7.1.2 OS)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am using Xiaomi Redmi Y1 (Running with 7.1.2 OS) when i try to fetch data from Firebase RealTime database using Query i am not able to fetch or listen to their listeners any suggestions or anybody has faced the issue before ?    See code below

```
Query myTopPostsQuery = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("con").child("cc").child(id)
                .orderByChild("created_at_millis");
        myTopPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: What's the behaviour, do you have an error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I am not getting any error not able to listen to ValueEventListener events and unable to get values in onDataChange

Comment: @NoumanCh No error i am not able to listen to ValueEventListener and get any values from DataSnapshot have you faced this issue before ?

Comment: attach your code here.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: Please add it to your question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

use this to track possible error:

```
Query myTopPostsQuery = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("con").child("cc").child(id)
        .orderByChild("created_at_millis");
    myTopPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        datatbaseError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah i did check Logs but it is not working . ValueEventListener is not getting called . I am facing this issue only in Redmi Y1 devices

Comment: try to debug the app.

Comment: I tried all possible solutions but no luck if you have any device with same config just try and see

Comment: i don't have dear.